# Production Laravel returning 404 requests CSS/JS

Tags: laravel, nginx

So, I have been having troubles for the past couple hours, to the point where I exhaust all my solutions that I have tried. My JS and CSS files are returning 404 requests (Laravel side).

- NGINX configuration

```
server {
    root /var/www/myapp/public;
    server_name subdomain.myapp.com;

    index index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
    }

    # Added afterwards and still did not fix my issue.
    location /public/css {
        alias /var/www/html/myapp/public/css/;
    }

    location /public/js {
        alias /var/www/html/myapp/public/js/;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.myapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.myapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = subdomain.myapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name subdomain.myapp.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I also did the following:

`npm run prod` to compile all my files. One thing I found odd, is why my `/css/app.css` has a chunk name of `/js/app`

```
                 Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
          /css/app.css   141 KiB       0  [emitted]         /js/app
            /js/app.js   798 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app
/js/app.js.LICENSE.txt  2.52 KiB          [emitted]
```

In addition to it, I also clear the cache for Laravel

`php artisan config:cache`

And my `app.blade.php` from layouts folder:

```html
<head>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" />
</head>
```

Comment: does your base url work correctly? do you see anything when you enter your base url?

Comment: the base url is heading to correct place. just giving me 404.

Comment: Does hardcoded path work like src=“/js/app.js” or src=“//mysite.com/js/app.js”.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem. It was in the nginx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in the nginx conf file. I needed to specify the rules for serving static files also: css, js, jpg, etc...

```
server {
  # serving static files
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }
}
```

For future reference, this have been tested on a Ubuntu 18.04 server, along with Laravel 7.